# How insert link in excel cell

Tags: google-apps-script

I generate excel with [google app script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/)
How insert link to web page in excel cell?

Comment: Are you trying to add a webpage link to a Google Sheet?  [Add Hyperlink To Google Sheet](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18070/add-a-link-in-google-spreadsheet-to-a-paragraph-in-docs)

Comment: Maybe you can use the class anchor but i don't know it's possible to use that to Google Spreadsheet.    example =>  var link = app.createAnchor(href, href).setId("link");

Answer (score 5):

You need to use 'setFormula' rather than 'setValue':

Eg:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var destinationCell = ss.getRange(1,1);
var link = "http://www.google.com";
var displayName = "My Link";
destinationCell.setFormula("=hyperlink(\""+link+"\";\"" + displayName + "\")");
```